# Geany editor messing up special characters

Tags: text, editor, geany

I don't know what I did or not but suddenly my geany editor is not printing some special characters like
(. , < - ) I have to type another character to make them appear, and I cannot find any answer on the internet, if someone knows the solution please answer.

Comment: Did you change the font settings recently?

Comment: @frlan  I did not change the font but I did change the theme by replacing the whole gtk2.0 folder(windows), because I wanted black sidebars too, which I could not get by themes available on geany. I have even reinstalled geany (theme was gone) but the problem still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change keyboard layout to English(Canada)
**In windows 10**
*settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard*
Override the input method to English(Canada)-US